# Estrutura de tabela para sistemas de amizades em PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou a desenvolver um sistema de amizades em meu sistema e gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de organizar a tabela que cuidará de tais registros `amigos`:

Já pensei em algo tipo:

```
Tabela "amigos" (apenas 3 colunas)
-----------------------------------
   id | usuario | usuarioamigo
```

Porém não sei se é a melhor maneira a se fazer e muito menos como poderia fazer a relação da consulta para saber se um usuário é amigo de outro usuário.

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso e como fazer?

Comment: Primeiro você deve verificar se um usuário também pode ser um amigo, se sim, receio que um auto-relacionamento possa vir a resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é a forma mais simples tendo *usuario* e *amigo*. Na consulta você verifica se *ID do usuário* combina com o *ID do amigo* e vice versa, em `usuario` ou em `usuarioamigo`

```
select * from amigos
where ( usuario = $IDUser or usuarioamigo = $IDUser )
  and ( usuario = $amigo  or usuarioamigo = $amigo  )
```

<sub>[**referência 1**](http://www.codedodle.com/2015/03/social-network-friends-relationship.html) , [**referência 2**](http://www.9lessons.info/2014/03/facebook-style-friend-request-system.html)</sub>

Comment: Acho que pude entender... Então essa organização da tabela `amigos` está correta?

Comment: @Igor, Sim está correta, não vejo motivo para evitar.

Comment: Não seria uma boa ideia utilizar dois inserts?  `INSERT INTO amigos values(amigo_id, usuario_id) VALUES (70, 80), (80, 70)`. Pois eu tive problemas no meu servidor (acho que por causa do `OR`), que está deixando tudo muito lento!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, também é uma opção, mas nesse caso serão muitas linhas duplicatas.